# Simplifying the entry of precise value (e.g. move by value in Y direction)

Tags: modeling

I don't know if this is a dumb question, but as I try to do more architectural work with Blender there is one thing which makes the simplest of actions more difficult. Consider this example which could apply to all kinds of operations.  Imagine I want to extrude one edge along a surface a specific distance. (Yes, I could loop cut, etc. but this question is about the data entry not this specific action.)

If you notice the Dy value seems to be the axis along which I want to extrude.  I want the Dy distance to be ".2".  If I simply enter ".2", that value is applied to the Dx value drawing it in a direction I did not want.  I can press "tab" and then enter the Dy value, but then I have to look up at which axis I am working with for every action.  Also, if I simply enter ".2" in this example it will draw the extrusion out from the object in the opposite direction I want.  In order get the direction I want I would have to enter a negative value, "-.2".

Unlike many CAD systems and Sketchup, Blender doesn't seem to utilize the information it has from the screen to make it easier to enter a precise value.  This is something Sketchup does extremely well.  It uses the information it has about the direction, axis, etc. from the mouse actions and applies any value entered to the appropriate value for the object.  That literally saves multiple steps for every operation which requires a precise value.

This is something which other systems do so well and makes it easy to use precise values for translations, sizing, etc. without having to think about the orientation of every object.

So my question is simply ... is there a setting which does something similar in Blender?

To be specific ... I want to select an edge, move the mouse to show the direction I want to extrude, enter a value and have it extrude in that direction.  The goal is to make the most common precise actions as simple as possible.

Thank you for your time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There _will_ be  Blenderish way.. but I think it will depend on the exact operation you want to execute Your illustration shows extrusion along a world axis:  Y.  If your Transform orientation is World, then that will just be: selection, followed by typing: **EY .2** But if you want axes on other standard Transform Orientations, or completely arbitrary (but defined) directions, the shortcuts short-methods will be different. Please show us some specific, frustrating examples :)clearly labelled,

Comment: I'll give an extremely simple example of the same thing.  Create a New model, switch to Edit mode, select the top face and extrude it inward by .5 without having to type "-.5".  In other words, having the extrude command use the direction you have indicated on the screen.

I can find many Blender ways to do this, what I was hoping is that there would be a way similar to other systems which doesn't require so many steps and can be a generalized rule making it easy.